# Key Error with Zip Function

Tags: python

While using zip, I know that there is a {} in my text that doesn't let the zip function run that many times. and I know that its the {} because when I erase them. the code runs perfectly. but I need the {} to be in that text.
To give you the big picture, 
I have a ready made text, that I want to "unpack" values from the 3 lists(the three lists are defined before this line of code comes), each will go to the appropriate place.

```
text = '''curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{
"name": "{}",
"lei": " ",
"parentId": "0",
"status": "ACTIVE",
"type": "1",
"country": "{}",
"region": "1",
"address": "{}",
"domains": "string.com"
}' 'http://qa-eu-entities.capitol.is/org'
'''


for i in zip(df['Name'], df['Country'], df['Address']):
    print(text.format(*i))
```

The Error that I get is KeyError

```
 KeyError: '\n  "name"'
```

I tried using json.loads and calling it on text, with no success.

Any idea what could be done differently?

Comment: I get `NameError: name 'df' is not defined` instead.

Comment: Well you don't have the file I have and you didn't define it as a dataframe

Comment: try writing the whole string on the same line

Comment: My code before that has the reading the the file, and defining the df['each column] = to a list

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the text contains extra `{` that's why it's making an error. I would suggest to use like this,

```
In [17]: text = """curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{
    ...: "name": "%s",
    ...: "lei": " ",
    ...: "parentId": "0",
    ...: "status": "ACTIVE",
    ...: "type": "1",
    ...: "country": "%s",
    ...: "region": "1",
    ...: "address": "%s",
    ...: "domains": "string.com"
    ...: }' 'http://qa-eu-entities.capitol.is/org'
    ...: """

In [19]: print(text %('hai','hey','test'))
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{
"name": "hai",
"lei": " ",
"parentId": "0",
"status": "ACTIVE",
"type": "1",
"country": "hey",
"region": "1",
"address": "test",
"domains": "string.com"
}' 'http://qa-eu-entities.capitol.is/org'
```

You case it will be like this,

```
for i in zip(df['Name'], df['Country'], df['Address']):
    print(text %(i))
```